# Rider Bug - Extension methods on C# 8 Nullable reference argument shows warning

Tags: c#, rider, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

> **Resolved**
>   Turns our Rider (2019.1) incorrectly shows this warning, but `dotnet build` are fine. It's fixed in v2019.2

I have a nullable property `MainBgColor`

```
public class Provider
{
   public string? MainBgColor { get; set; }
}
```

and I have an extension method that returns `string.Empty` if the input is null.

```
public static string EmptyIfNull(this string input) => input ?? string.Empty;
```

but when I try to use this

```
var provider = GetTheProviderSomehow();
var logo = provider.MainBgColor.EmptyIfNull();
```

I get the warning generated by c#8 compiller

```
[CS8604] Possible null reference argument for parameter 'input' in 'string ProviderExtensions.EmptyIfNull(string input)'.
```

My question is, this would be perfectly fine because I am checking for null (inside the extension method) without the nullable reference type feature on. Why is it still comaplaining?

If I change the extention method to allow `nullable` `string?` - then the compiller doesn't think it's a valid extension method for `provider.Logo`.

[image]

Is this an expected feature for C#8 nullable reference type? am I not supposed to use extension methods for one of the nullable types?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? I know it's probably all there, but it is easier for people to check for themselves if they can just copy and paste it.

Comment: Are you on the latest preview? Changing the signature to have a `string?` parameter is working as expected for me.

Comment: Thanks, this is an issue with the IDE (Rider) it keeps showing red but builds fine.

Comment: Next time, try `dotnet build` to see the *actual* errors and warnings. Both Rider and Visual Studio Intellisense get things wrong at this time. Sometimes all you need to do is just close the file and reopen it. This can get tedious

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the extension method as accepting a nullable string.

Comment: I tried that, that shows `Can't resolve NullIfEmpty` - I have memtioned this in my question.

Comment: I have updated the question and included the screenshot.